# How to change the permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, user-accounts, file-permissions

How do I set all *.java files in the current directory and all its sub directories to have read permission to all users?

I also want to set all files of at least 1 kilobyte in size in the current directory and all sub directories to have a group of admin.

Comment: Voting to move to Super User, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 5):

**Alternative:** To set read permission for all .java files in the current directory, use this command:

```
chmod -R 444 *.java
```

To set all files of at least 1 kilobyte in size in the current directory and all sub directories to have a group of admin.

```
find /yourdirectorypath -size +1k -exec chgrp admin {} \;
```

Note: *the "-R" indicates recursive which will cover your sub directories as well*

Comment: I don't think you want `-R` on the `chgrp` command since `find` is doing the recursion for you.

Comment: Dennis--if you notice, he only uses -R on the chmod, not on the chgrp.  He isn't using find on the chmod, because it has built-in recursion.

Comment: @CarlF: Reading the revision history, it would appear that the answer was edited. When Dennis commented, the `chgrp` had a `-R` on it.

Comment: I should have stated that change here in the comments but I got busy.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I set all *.java files in the current directory and all its sub directories to have read permission to all users?

In bash ≥4.0 and zsh:

```
chmod a+r ./**/*.java
```

On any POSIX-compliant system (i.e. any non-antique unix variant and more):

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec chmod a+r {} +
```

> Set all files of at least 1 kilobyte in size in the current directory and all sub directories to have a group of admin.

In zsh:

```
chgrp admin ./**/*(.L+1023)
```

On any POSIX-compliant system:

```
find . -type f -size +1023c -exec chgrp admin {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find and xargs

```
find . -name \*.java | xargs chmod o+r
```

or

```
find . -name \*.java -print0 | xargs -0 chmod o+r
```

The second version handles spaces in file or directory names.

You may need to fix directory permissions as well.

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod o+rx
```

You can avoid updating permissions which are already correct. Check the man page for find and review the section on permissions.

Comment: Rather than use xargs, use the simpler, robust and POSIX-compliant `find . -type d -exec chmod o+r {} +`.

Answer (score 0):

To set read permission for all .java files in the current directory, use this command

```
chmod +r *.java
```

Comment: The question asked about subdirectories, which this answer does not cover.